# How to send email using Angular and Node server?

Tags: node.js, angular

I am able to send emails with nodejs using nodemailer but my project is in angular 6. I don't know how to integrate that nodejs code into my angular.I just want it for my website contact us forum. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should add a piece of code and point a specific issue.
But what I understand is that you try to run a server side code on the client side which is not always feasible.

Comment: @davidonet Thank you for your comment. I have downloaded a nodejs project sample from the internet which is working fine now I want to use that code in my angular project. I don't have any idea regarding this.

Comment: Do you have a server in your angular project ? Could you post some code ?

Comment: @davidonet, simply I want to send mail from contact page in angular using nodejs  and angular. Is it possible?.

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: Can you please guide me on it else can I have a snippet of it.  I am trying to add my source code but it was showing some errors while submitting I am new to stack overflow too.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to create a way of allowing your Angular code to talk to your Node.js code, typically you'd use a REST API using Http or Express.

For example, using Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 8081;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Allow callers to send an email message
app.post('/send_email', function(req, res){
    console.log('send_email body: ',  req.body);
    sendEmail(req.body);
    res.status(201).json({status: 'success' });
});

app.listen(port);

function sendEmail(emailObj) {
    // Send the mail
}
```

In Angular you can use the HttpClient module to call this, for example:

```
// Replace the url root as necessary
this.httpClient.post("http://127.0.0.1:8081/send_email",
    {
        "email": "user1@example.com",
        "message": "Test message"
    })
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
        },
        error => {
            console.log("Error", error);
        }
    );
```

It's worth noting that you will need to provide some authorization mechanism in the REST endpoint (e.g. POST send_email), since you don't want any old client sending mails.

Comment: Thank you @Terry Lennox. Am I need to run the node and angular individually?.

Comment: Yes, you'd run the node.js process server-side, e.g. node index.js, and the Angular 6 code will run on the client.

Comment: Thank you very much. You really saved my day. Cheers, buddy :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to help!